# How can I securely store my remote database connection string in a VB.Net application?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am ready to deploy a VB.Net application that is going to be used by users all around the world, connecting to a hosted SQL Server database online. As the server is not on my domain, I connect via IP address using SQL username and password.

My big concern is that someone can reverse engineer the application and retrieve the connection string, complete with IP, username and password and login to the database easily.

My question is, what is the correct way to store and retrieve the SQL connection string in this scenario?

As users will be connecting to a hosted server, I cannot utilise Windows Authentication.

I have read some conflicting advice that anything stored in the app.config file is secured, whilst others advising to encrypt the string within the app.config file.

Visual Studio is able to generate a connection string without a password and I can retrieve data, but I'm sure that once deployed, without the password existing in the project itself, it will essentially fail.

What's the best practice and most secure way to prevent this? (if it all possible!)

Comment: I am not entirely sure of what I am about to say but, the way I see it, the SQL server IP/Domain has to be embedded into the program or on a config file that the software will request (this information will be always public no matter what).  For this the only option is to secure the server.  The username and password to connect to the database you can create a login information for each one of the users and create a login form.  If the software is going to be used from the same computer that belongs to the same user, you can restrict that user and allow it to connect to the DB from that host.

Comment: Is this a stand alone .net WinForms client app or a web hosted app like a website via ASP.NET with MVC or similar?  Is your target SQL server a newer version like SQL 2016.  Is the SQL server target in Azure?  Is your program interactive with a user such that you could present a username password login box during the startup process ?    Does the owner of the SQL Server db know you are doing this and do they have an existing solution so that you do not create something new on your own.  These questions can open up some possibilities to a non-hardcoded solution.

Comment: Also make sure that you grant only the permits that each user require and assign those permits to the specific database.  On the server if you can have remote access to it, make sure that the user with permits to modify the sql server configuration can connect only from the same server.  If you dont have remote access to the server, then make sure is a single user with those permits, secure password and strong username and password (do not use admin or administrator as username).  Last make sure that the root user has a secure password and that can connect only from the server itself.

Comment: That's why databases have a user management, too. Normally each user that logs in to your application should actually authenticate against the DB server. For anonymous access, you should consider creating an appropriately permitted DB user without a password. Usually, this is a read-only user.